# Messages from .properties file do not display UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

As the title says, I can only add that if I enter ą ę ó manually in html file, it's fine.

ViewResolver:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

example of html input:

```
<h2><p th:text="#{homepage.greeting}">Welcome</p></h2>
```

inside the  tag of the html file:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

In IntelliJ Idea I have set project encoding to UTF-8, default encoding for properties files to UTF-8
[image]

And I honestly have no idea where is the problem. When I change locale to pl, this is the output:
[image]

Sorry but I can't post images yet.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried this filter in web.xml, still no luck.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: works for me. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Here's the deal:

I had the following code:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

**Option 1:**
Just add this as another property:

```
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

**Option 2:**
Changed it to:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

If you change it to reloadable, keep in mind to also change the property value from "messages" to "classpath:messages". For some reason it couldn't find the message bundle if I didn't change it.

Answer (score 2):

When you use ResourceBundleMessageSource object, you need to set default encoding as follows:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() { 
    ResourceBundleMessageSource resource = 
            new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resource.setBasename("messages");
    resource.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resource;    
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this answer different than mine? In my answer's option 1, I am setting the default encoding.

Comment: You may right, I also think the two solutions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting default encoding is not enough, have to create properties files in UTF-8 format also.

For more details please refer [SpringBoot - UTF-8 Doesnt work in messages.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112852/springboot-utf-8-doesnt-work-in-messages-properties)