# SpringBoot - UTF-8 Doesnt work in messages.properties

Tags: spring, utf-8, thymeleaf

### **¿What's the problem?**

I can't display in UTF-8 the messages I got in messages.properties.

An example

```
<h1 id="logo">Electrónico</h1>
```

this works okay but when I try to use my message source like this

```
<h1 id="logo" th:text="#{titulo.electronico}">Electrónico</h1>
```

I get "Electr�nico" instead of Electrónico

This is my configuration

**application.properties**

```
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.Demo</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

**Demo class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ServletInitializer.class**

```
@Configuration
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Demo.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
        registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
      CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
      filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
      filter.setForceEncoding(true);
      return filter;
    }
}
```

If you need more information about my configuration I can edit it.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include your servlet config?

Comment: Your `messages.properties` file must be created in the `UTF-8` as well.

Comment: @Artem Bilan how can I do that?

Comment: Use some editor which supports encoding switching. Or create that file from IDE with encoding option for `properties` files. E.g. IDEA: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: @ArtemBilan thank you! I fixed it just switching its encoding with notepad.

Comment: :-) Great! I think you won't mind if I move it to an answer to accept some reputation from you

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thank for you help, i have the same problem message.properties but i used the IDE Eclipse. So i click with click right button in the file and i go to the propeties. When open the window i saw **Text file encoding** and i changed for UTF-8 and worked!!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To read any file in the `UTF-8` encoding it must be created in the `UTF-8` before.

Use some editor which supports encoding switching. Or create that file from IDE with encoding option for properties files. E.g. IDEA: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: Just adding more... From linux, "file file.properties" will return ASCII or ISO-8559 if it is wrong, and you can convert using "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file.properties -o newfile".

Comment: For some reason IDEA prevents changing encoding for properties files...

Comment: This worked: created a new file in sublime, pasted the contents of the properties, saved as UTF-8 overwritting the previous and voila.

Answer (score 32):

Hopefully this may help others. The various `code` solutions didn't work in my case but an editor settings did.

If you are using intellij go to `file encoding` and set global and project encoding to UTF-8, same goes for the `default encoding for properties files` and -very important- check the `Transaparent native-to-ascii conversion`.

[image: Intellij File Encoding]

If you open the file with a decent text editor you will notice that some characters are written with their UTF-8 version such as

> é `->` \u00E9

In my case the change didn't triggered a change for GIT so I had to make a "fake" modification to the file in order to do a commit and push.

Comment: with your solution, my utf-8 character display correctly but when I commit and push on git, It damages (like your example). how can I fix it?

Comment: if I check "Transaparent native-to-ascii conversion" validation message with utf-8 character display correctly but after push on git, they damaged and other user can't work.

Comment: Awesome. This has really helped me to solve the issues with messages.properties files on a Spring MVC project with the UTF-8 data on IntelliJ IDEA. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note: `é` has the Unicode code point `U+00E9` and can be represented as `\u00E9` in messages properties. It is encoded as `0x00E9`  in UTF-16, but *in UTF-8 it is `0xC3A9`!* https://unicode-table.com/en/00E9/

Comment: @NASRIN how could you bypass the issue when pushing the code to GIT?

Answer (score 25):

In my case, I forgot `messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")`, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160812185301/http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/42668-solution-for-utf-8-encoding-problem-inside-property-files).

Comment: by the way, it doesn't need to be ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. setDefaultEncoding is defined in AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource thus inherited by ResourceBundleMessageSource too.

Comment: Default encoding in Spring Boot is already UTF-8 if you use the standard auto-configured MessageSource.  You only need to set this if you define your own MessageSource bean, which will prevent auto-configuration.

Answer (score 5):

At least in my case the problem was in messages.properties files. Because Eclipse (STS in my case) use by default ISO-8859-1 encoding.
[image]

So, just changing it to UTF-8 did the trick. But be careful, because during the conversion process (I did it after adding content) some characters can be replaced with symbols like diamonds, etc.

[image]

Comment: It is really helpful for eclipse STS